# Combining excel tabs from different workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel

Several workbooks all with the same template sheet/tab labelled A amongst other tabs.
Can I get all the tabs labelled A onto one workbook quickly? (like how power query can combine/append the same table in different workbooks).

Thank you.

Comment: Does [How to Copy and Move a Sheet in Excel using VBA](https://excelchamps.com/vba/copy-sheet/#Copy_Multiple_Sheets_to_the_New_Workbook) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following macro:

```
Sub CombineWorkbooks()

'Declare variables
Dim Path As String, FileName As String
Dim wkb As Workbook, wkbNew As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet, wksNew As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim FilesInFolder As Variant
Dim i As Integer

'Turn off screen updating to speed up code execution
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Set the path to the folder containing the workbooks
FolderPath = "C:\Your\Folder\Path\"

'Get all files in the folder
FilesInFolder = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx")

'Create a new workbook to copy the sheets to
Set wkbNew = Workbooks.Add

'Loop through all files in the folder
Do While FilesInFolder <> ""

    'Open the workbook
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FilesInFolder)

    'Loop through all sheets in the workbook
    For Each wks In wkb.Sheets

        'Check if the sheet is named "A"
        If wks.Name = "A" Then

            'Copy the sheet to the new workbook
            wks.Copy After:=wkbNew.Sheets(wkbNew.Sheets.Count)
            Set wksNew = wkbNew.Sheets(wkbNew.Sheets.Count)

            'Rename the sheet to the original workbook name
            wksNew.Name = wkb.Name

            'Close the original workbook without saving changes
            wkb.Close False

        End If
    Next wks

    'Get the next file in the folder
    FilesInFolder = Dir

Loop

'Save and close the new workbook
wkbNew.SaveAs FolderPath & "CombinedSheets.xlsx"
wkbNew.Close

'Turn on screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Notify user that the code has finished running
MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```